# Error in Mounting jffs2 file system in Nandflash

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, bsp, rootfs, jffs2

I m using at91sam9m10g45ek board.i want to boot from Nandflash.
linux 3.12 not able to mount jffs2 during booting from nandflash.
My u-boot Parameter :

bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk **mtdparts=atmel_nand:256k(bootstrap)ro,512k(uboot)ro,256k(env),256k(env_redundant),256k(spare),512k(dtb),6M(kernel)ro,-(rootfs) root=/dev/mtdblock7 rw rootfstype=jffs2**

Error:

**VFS: Cannot open root device "mtdblock7" or unknown-block(31,7): error -19
Please append a correct "root=" boot option;**

How to resolve this??plz help me i m new in this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what did you install in NAND flash for a rootfs, and at what NAND address is it written at? Do you have a boot log of the last working kernel and rootfs? FYI UBIFS is preferred over JFFS2 when using NAND.  E.G. take a look at http://www.at91.com/discussions/viewtopic.php/f,12/t,23189.html